# Reding XML from Web Page using VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to read the XML codes generated by the website, but it always fails, I am not much a programmer mostly worked in Server Domain. Can you please help me get this working.

What I am trying to do is, I am making a small utility which will help me to creates reports from the Adobe Connect. I am referring the Adobe Connect 9 Web services API. (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/connect_9_webservices.pdf)

Earlier I used to get the 407 authentication error but now with the below code, I think its authenticating with the default cred.

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Xml


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim theProxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
        Dim aResp As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy, HttpWebResponse)
        ' Print the Proxy Url to the console.

        If theProxy IsNot Nothing Then
            theProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        End If

        Try
            Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("https://my.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=common-info")
            'MsgBox("Authentnticated")

            Do While (reader.Read())
                Select Case reader.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.
                        MsgBox("<" + reader.Name)
                        If reader.HasAttributes Then 'If attributes exist
                            While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
                                'Display attribute name and value.
                                MsgBox(" {0}='{1}'", reader.Name, reader.Value)
                            End While
                        End If
                        MsgBox(">")
                    Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                        MsgBox(reader.Value)
                    Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.
                        MsgBox("</" + reader.Name)
                        MsgBox(">")
                End Select
            Loop
            Console.ReadLine()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Above URL generates the following XML on webpage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <status code="ok"/>
    <OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN><token/></OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN>
    <common time-zone-java-id="UTC" time-zone-id="85" locale="en">
        <cookie>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</cookie>
        <date>2014-06-13T15:07:03.573+00:00</date>
        <host>https://my.adobeconnect.com</host>
        <local-host>pcparapp04</local-host>
        <admin-host>arcps.adobeconnect.com</admin-host>
        <url>/api/xml?action=common-info</url>
        <version>9.2.2</version>
        <product-notification>true</product-notification>
        <account account-id="295153"/>
        <user-agent>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; EIE10;ENINWOL)</user-agent>
        <mobile-app-package>air.com.adobe.connectpro</mobile-app-package>
    </common>
    <reg-user>
        <is-reg-user>false</is-reg-user>
    </reg-user>
</results>
```

I need to take the take information from the above XML like contents of  tags.

Hey Chris, all the code worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.

just a small query how do I check attributes of a tag with special char in their name.
ex:

so when i write

dim x = z..@sco-id

it does not accept sco-id, how do I use attribute name like @sco-id or @transaction-id

Once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of VB (2008 or greater) you can use something called XML literals which makes life really easy:

```vb
    Dim RemoteURL = "https://my.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=common-info"
    Dim X = XDocument.Load(RemoteURL)
    Dim Cookie = X.<results>.<common>.<cookie>.Value
```

If you need to use the proxy code you can use the longer version that downloads the string and parses it:

```vb
    Dim remoteURL = "https://my.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=common-info"
    Dim remoteText As String = Nothing
    Using WC As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim theProxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
        theProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        WC.Proxy = theProxy
        remoteText = WC.DownloadString(remoteURL)
    End Using

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteText) Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("No data was returned from remote URL")
    End If

    Dim X = XDocument.Parse(remoteText)
    Dim Cookie = X.<results>.<common>.<cookie>.Value
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, Again it filed to authenticate the proxy, at Xdocumnet.load The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: It worked, perfect. just added following in app.config file. <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"> </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>